# docker run with -p and a single port (instead of mapping)

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

What is the different between the following commands when creating a container in docker?

`docker run -d -p 8080 sample/image`

and

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 sample/image`

I have seen majority of them use the second command, but I am not sure if they mean different things, or if the first is shorthand.

I couldn't find any material on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
docker run -d -p 8080 sample/image
```

Exposes port `8080` of the container as an arbitrary port on the host. Which port that is is up to Docker.

Whereas,

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 sample/image
```

Exposes port `8080` of the container as port `8080` on the host.

---

In both cases, you can see the mapping using `docker inspect`, or even `docker ps`:

```
380af8c2bcc6  ubuntu  "bash"  15 seconds ago  Up 13 seconds  0.0.0.0:32768->1234/tcp elegant_meitner
```

In this case, port `1234` of the container is exposed as port `32768` on the host.